# Displaying only actual values on the DateTimeAxis

Tags: oxyplot

If I set the `"HH:mm"` format for axis, time displayed on the axis is rounded to every 30 minutes and intermediate times are added as well, which are not present in data. How to display only actual times and without rounding?

For example this is the data and this should be displayed on the axis:

```
18:02                           18:58
```

But instead this is displayed on the axis which is not what I want:

```
18:00           18:30           19:00
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by subclassing `DateTimeAxis` and overriding `GetTickValues`.

`DateTimeAxis.ToDouble` is handy there to convert from `DateTime` to `double`.

Comment: Any example of this?